# SSL handshake error in Volley android

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, android-volley

I am trying to do ssl pining from my volley library to my web server who accepts only connection with valid certificate. I am getting an SSL handshake error. I am using the code below for loading the certificate:

```
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    // From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssl_bundle);
    Certificate ca;
    try {
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return  new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

And getting the below error:

```
11-10 20:15:04.464 26024-26024/com.mk.buzz D/LoginTask: error: Could not connect to Buzz service. Please try again and check your internet connection.
                                                    com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:158)
                                                        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
                                                     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:441)
                                                        at mk.blob.buzz.Util.NoSSLv3SocketFactory$DelegateSSLSocket.startHandshake(NoSSLv3SocketFactory.java:158)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:212)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1322)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1410)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:466)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:257)
                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
                                                        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114) 
                                                        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                                                            ... 19 more
                                                            Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                                                                ... 19 more
                                                            Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x7f93931300: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                    error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x7f725e0e40:0x00000001)
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
                                                                    ... 18 more
                                                     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x7f93931300: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                    error:100c543e:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x7f725e0d80:0x00000001)
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
                                                                ... 18 more
                                                     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x7f93931300: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                    error:100c543e:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x7f725e0d80:0x00000001)
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
                                                            ... 18 more
```

Any idea how to fix i tried everything :/

Comment: I am not expert in all the inner workings of Conscrypt, but `TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK` feels like a separate problem from the certificate itself.

Comment: I can see that the certificate is red but not sure where i am making things bad :/

Comment: I am not sure what "the certificate is red" means. `TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK` to me suggests that your server only supports certain SSL/TLS variants, and that what it supports does not line up with what Android supports. If you were getting this error with an ordinary server (one without a custom SSL cert), I would suggest using [the Qualys SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to see what the server is doing. I am not certain how to do this sort of check with a private SSL cert, though.